# How to organize updated row logging

Tags: sql-server, database, logging

I have some tables in Sql Server. I want to log row, if row is updated or deleted. how can I organize this process?

Sample table structure:

```
    [uniqueGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    *[kod_a] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    *[kod_b] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    *[kod_c] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    *[kod_d] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [sname] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [payment] money NULL
```

*Note:* marked columns (kod_a, kod_b, kod_c, kod_d) are unique constaint together. Another tables also in same structure, columns count may be different.

some idea , please.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you need an audit trail whenever a row is deleted or updated? What do you need to log? Just the data? The user? Anything else?

Comment: I want to log in another table changed row in initial form, and by whom it was changed, datetime and some adition info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old data can be exposed in a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) using the [Deleted table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx). I'll stub out a quick example to get you started.

```
create trigger YourTriggerName on YourTable
after update, delete
as
    /* Deleted table contains the "old" values before the update/delete operation */
    insert into YourLoggingTable
        (UniqueGUID, kod_a, ..., payment, DateModified)
        select UniqueGUID, kod_a, ..., payment, getdate()
            from Deleted 
go
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your updates are going through a single stored procedure you could create and execute an audit stored procedure when you update or delete data in this table.

Triggers are great, but they can sometimes cause pain. If possible avoid using them.

Comment: In my experience, this technique is too restrictive and likely to be unintentionally circumvented. You'll never capture a change made outside of the stored procedure using this technique (e.g., a DBA makes a quick data fix with an update statement in SSMS). That's why I'd prefer a trigger here. No matter how/where the data is changed, the change will be captured.

Comment: I agree with Joe, IMO in this case using triggers is a more secure strategy